# Quickbook Data in to Sql server using SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, quickbooks

I need to all data of quickbook file `(.qbw)` conveted to my SQL Server database. these data should be driven using SDK. is it possible using asp.net.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you have not shown any working or research for yourself. Please edit the question to show what you've done and what issues you've had with it.

Comment: i am woking to integration quickbook in my own asp.net website so how should i have to mention other in my question. please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SQL Server Integration service (SSIS)` tools for your idea. In SSIS you can have script component that write with C# language as a source of data and use OLD DB as a destination that connected to you destination table on the SQL Server database.

**EDIT**

You can use C# and VB Language for script component

Samples:

[Script Component as Source - SSIS](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/38-Script-Component-as-Source-SSIS.html)

[SSIS – Using a Script Component as a Source](http://www.ssistalk.com/2007/04/04/ssis-using-a-script-component-as-a-source/)

[Creating a Source with the Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx)

Comment: can you please give some example so i can follow that steps...

Comment: @Sonagara Hitesh. please see my edit